# Only specify IPv6 suffix in DSM

Tags: ipv6, synology

I'm using a dual stack connection at home and have a DS213+. As my public IP (both v4 and v6) is dynamic, I'd like to only specify a suffix in my Diskstation's network configuration. My router supports DHCPv6, offers IA_PD and IA_NA.

My ISP delegates a random /64 to my router each time I connect and I want my Diskstation to use this prefix plus a static suffix. I did NOT find any option to do this.

Comment: The first thing I would do would be to complain to the ISP about their screwed up IPv6 deployment.

Comment: "We do this for privacy reasons." - Besides, changing that is not in my reach.

Comment: Oh, you must be in Germany. You'll have to find some way to get this turned off; IPv6 was not meant to be deployed like this, and you'll find that most devices will not handle it.

Comment: Besides... DSM does not even have an option to set multiple v6 addresses...